# Seeding problem for a 3-way bracket

Tags: probability, ranking, games

I apologize in advance if this is not the correct place for this question. I'm going to be running a 36-person tournament in a certain activity, with the first two rounds being 3-way competitions (36->12->4).

My question is how to fairly seed these 3-way tournaments. Before the round of 36, I'll have a good idea of player strength, and the seeds will reflect that strength. I can either decide matchups by seed or by a rough estimation of player strength.

My idea was to give the highest strength of schedule to the 36th seed, the 2nd-highest to the 35th seed, etc. Is there any good method out there for figuring out matchups so that this can happen, or is there another method which would be appropriate for seeding such matchups?

Comment: What does "strength of schedule" mean?

Comment: By "strength of schedule", I mean the strength of the opponents that a player would have to face in the first round. For instance, if I had a matchup of the 1-13-36 seeds in the first round, and each player had strength (37-seed), the 1st seed would have schedule strength (37-13)+(37-36)=25.

Comment: What matters to the players (all of them, really) is presumably their chance of winning the first round. That depends on how the strength of the other two combines into win-probability.

Comment: Re-reading your answer makes it more clear. I think the most important thing here is whether or not the top-players are more evenly matched than the bottom players. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, scheduling based on seeding seems to be set up to improve the chance to retain the better players.

Here's one obvious possibility:

Going by seed, if we want to maximize the chances of keeping the top few seeds, we want the highest seed they face to be low and within that, the average seed they face to be fairly low.

One approach: Consider that the second-best player in each group is the 'main danger' to the top seeds. We can hold the average of the seedings of the 2nd and 3rd ranked player in each group constant, while keeping the lowest of the second-ranked seeds for the top seed, the second-lowest second-ranked player for the second seed and so on:

```
 1 24 25
 2 23 26
 3 22 27
 4 21 28
 5 20 29
 6 19 30
 7 18 31
 8 17 32
 9 16 33
10 15 34
11 14 35
12 13 36
```

This has the advantage that the top second-ranked players also have a reasonable chance to go through (it's not *that* much worse being 13th seed than 12th), so the difficulty of the draw for the top 2/3 of players seems to increase relatively smoothly. It might be particularly appropriate for the top 2/3 of players if the strengths in the bottom third are more nearly even than in the top groups (though the bottom-ranked players might then argue that the schedule for 36 is easier than for 25).

You could flip the third column top to bottom, but it's not clear to me that it's better. This would make the progression from easy to hard more rapid as you go down the first column of seed (weighting it more strongly to the top few seeds):

```
 1 24 36
 2 23 35
 3 22 34
 4 21 33
 5 20 32
 6 19 31
 7 18 30
 8 17 29
 9 16 28
10 15 27
11 14 26
12 13 25
```

This could be more suitable, for example, if the strength in the bottom third goes down more quickly than in the top groups (if the top seeds were more nearly evenly matched than the lowest-ranked 12 players were). If you want to focus on the task for the bottom 12 players, this makes the progression in difficulty more clear for them.

If you have some model for the chances of going through that might give you a better idea of which of those schedules will have the best chances of giving outcomes that are 'desirable'.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, but it would seem unfair to the 25 seed.

Comment: I don't see how. Can you explain? Note in particular, that in the top schedule I give, the 25th seed has only a fractionally harder task than the 24th seed, so if it is unfair on 25, it presumably must also be unfair on 24.

Comment: Using the top model: If we expect the #1-#2 gap to be greater than the, say, #35-#36, I would much rather be the #36 than #25. I think we're talking about different things: for the top 2/3 both models work fantastically, while things are different for the bottom 1/3. However, I'm not sure it is possible to make a perfect schedule for the entire population of players.

Comment: On thinking about it, I can see that if the strengths flatten out more as you go down, #25 might complain that #36 has a slightly easier task. And then #24 might have a similar complaint. The second schedule might suit you better from several viewpoints.